# What are the most common newbie pitfalls of changing a refrigerator seals?

Tags: refrigerator

I would like to replace the seals on a subzero refrigerator. The videos on youTube make it look easy and I have bought the replacement seal form the subzero.  I am interested in being informed so as to avoid making newbie errors and improving the chances of installing it correctly the first time.  This is will be my first attempt at replacing a seal.

What are the common pitfalls to avoid regarding this task?  Google did not return a good answer.

Any 'lessons-learned' are appreciated.

Comment: make sure it fits before you rip the old one off.

Comment: I was thinking the same, they are fairly simple.+